# How to upload .r file into azure ml studio and run it?

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a R file and I want to run the same in azureML studio. 
After running the codes in Rstudio I zip the r file and import it into Azure studio's datasets.I pull the dataset and Execute R script module to the experiment and attach script bundle port to the zip file. It asks for a src path which I am not sure of. When I run, it says CONNECTION NOT FOUND.

What should be done to find the connection?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the R script in the zip folder by referring to it through the `Execute R Script` module.

Use `source("src/YourScriptName.r")` for executing YourScriptName.r inside the zip file.